# Does Rails 2 support JSON POST requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, ruby-on-rails-2

When I send JSON data in a POST request, my controller doesn't see the data. The equivalent XML works fine, so is JSON just not supported by Rails 2? Is there some other gem that I need to install?

I'm using Rails 2.0.2, and I've generated the scaffolding for my model. I can use the generated code to create records using the browser, or I can create records by sending XML POST requests with curl.

Now I want to change the generated code to support JSON instead of XML. I replaced the `format.xml` calls with `format.json`, and GET requests now give me back nice JSON.

However, when I try to create a record by sending a JSON POST request, none of the parameters are passed to my controller.

To track down the problem, I replaced the `create()` method of my controller with this:

```
# POST /some_models
# POST /some_models.json
def create
    render :json => params
end
```

This will just dump the content of the `params` hash so I can see what's being passed.

I test it with XML data using this curl statement:

```
curl --request POST --cookie cookies.txt -d "<some_model version='6.6' order_by='606'/>" -H "Content-Type:text/xml" http://localhost:3000/some_models.xml
```

That works fine, and I see this output:

```
{"some_model": {"version": "6.6", "order_by": "606"}, "format": "xml", "action": "create", "controller": "some_models"}
```

Now I try the equivalent with JSON data:

```
curl --request POST --cookie cookies.txt -d '{ "some_model": {"version": "6.6", "order_by": 606} }' -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:3000/some_models.json
```

Now I don't get a `some_model` key in the `params` hash:

```
{"format": "json", "action": "create", "controller": "some_models"}
```

Comment: The JSON being posted isn't quite valid. The strings in the data need to be in double-quotes -- `-d '{ "some_model": {"version": "6.6", "order_by": 606} }'`.

Comment: Just a quick comment - I a using ruby '2.1.1' and 'rails', '4.1.6 and in JAvascript use  JSON to send data to rails controller.  I can post the code if that is any help.  Pierre

Comment: I tried the quotes both ways, @Jonathan, with no difference in behaviour. I've updated the question to match your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, @user1854802, but I have found several examples of sending this kind of request to Rails 4. I'm asking specifically about Rails 2 to see if it's even supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [article from 25th May 2008](http://www.digitalhobbit.com/2008/05/25/rails-21-and-incoming-json-requests/):

> Luckily, it turns out that full support for JSON was 
>   added to Rails in April [2008], making it a first class citizen 
>   along with XML and regular URL-encoded form fields. 
>   This functionality will be officially released in Rails 2.1

The article mentions that previous to Rails 2.1, this json_request plugin was used:

https://github.com/assaf/labnotes/tree/master/ruby/rails_plugins/json_request/